# How to reverse the direction of applying texture in the object CylinderGeometry?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, texture-mapping

How to reverse the direction of applying texture in the object CylinderGeometry?

```
var obj = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.CylinderGeometry(20, 15, 1, 20),
    new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x000000}) //the material is later changed to the correct
);
```

Thank you in advance for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean? Can you be more specific?

Comment: It was about what we present below. Thanks :)

Comment: @JarosławOsmólski Is this what you mean by "reverse the direction"? `texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping; texture.repeat.set( - 1, 1 );`

Comment: Thanks. But I did not want to change yourself texture on the object. Because I impose on him a large amount of tekstrur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function works:

```
        var invertTextureOnCylinderGeometry = function(obj) {
            var faceVertexes = obj.geometry.faceVertexUvs[0];
            var faceVertexesLength = faceVertexes.length;
            var divisionT = 1 / (faceVertexesLength * 0.25);
            faceVertexes.map(function(face, index) {
                if (index < 0.5*faceVertexesLength) {
                    var thisIndexDivision = [
                        Math.floor(index/2) * divisionT,
                        Math.ceil((index+divisionT)/2) * divisionT
                    ];
                    if (index % 2) {
                        face[0].set(1, thisIndexDivision[0]);
                        face[1].set(1, thisIndexDivision[1]);
                        face[2].set(0, thisIndexDivision[1]);
                    } else {
                        face[0].set(0, thisIndexDivision[0]);
                        face[1].set(1, thisIndexDivision[0]);
                        face[2].set(0, thisIndexDivision[1]);
                    }
                }
            });
            obj.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
        };
```

Comment: `nieparzyste` and `parzyste`? Language should be English on SO.

Comment: It was only a temporary easier for me. I removed. Comment here and so is unnecessary.